# Additional right axis for groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I'm trying to make a right-side axis title (but only a title) for grouped (`facet_grid()`) variables.

I have `tried the scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = (name= "title")` command, it didn't work without a variable which I don't have. I have also tried `axis.title.y.right = element_text("Sex of groups")` element in the theme function. It didn't work either.

What I have as code is this:

```
temp.data = data.frame (Species  = rep(c("A","B"),each=2, times=2),
                           Status = rep(c("An","Bac"), times=4),
                           Sex = rep(c("Male","Female"), each=4, times=1),
                           Proportion = c(6.86, 7.65, 30.13, 35.71, 7.13, 10.33, 29.24, 31.09))

ggplot(temp.data, aes(x = Species, y = Proportion, fill = Status)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = position_dodge(width = 0.73), width=.67) +
  facet_grid(Sex ~ .) + xlab("X title") + 
  ylab("Y title") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Status", labels = c("A","B"),
                    values = c("#0d4e04","#a36424")) +
 # scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = (name= "Sex of groups")) +
  theme_light() + theme(legend.title= element_text(size = 8),
                        legend.title.align=0.5,
                        legend.position = c(),
                        legend.background=element_blank(),
                        legend.text=element_text(size=7),
                        legend.key.size = unit(0.6, 'cm'),
                        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 9),
                        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 9),
                        axis.title.y.right = element_text("Sex of groups"),
                        strip.background = element_rect(
                          color="lightgrey", fill="white", size=0.5, linetype="solid"),
                        strip.text.y = element_text(color = "darkgrey", face = "bold"))
```

This is the graph I have produced:

[image]

So basically I'm looking for a way to put a title on the right Y axis, just near the facetted groups. It'd be great to know, if you know a solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you were on the right track. You could add your title via a duplicated y scale using `scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name= "Sex of groups"))`. Besides that we need some additional `theme` adjustments to get rid of the axis text and ticks where the latter also requires to set the tick length to 0:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(temp.data, aes(x = Species, y = Proportion, fill = Status)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.73), width = .67) +
  facet_grid(Sex ~ .) +
  xlab("X title") +
  ylab("Y title") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = "Status", labels = c("A", "B"),
    values = c("#0d4e04", "#a36424")
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name= "Sex of groups")) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    legend.title = element_text(size = 8),
    legend.title.align = 0.5,
    legend.position = c(),
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 7),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.6, "cm"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 9),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 9),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(l = 5.5)),
    axis.text.y.right = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.length.y.right = unit(0, "pt"),
    strip.background = element_rect(
      color = "lightgrey", fill = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"
    ),
    strip.text.y = element_text(color = "darkgrey", face = "bold")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to say that though, under `theme()`, these elements do the half of the trick: `axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank()` and `axis.ticks.length.y.right = unit(0, "pt")`

Comment: Yeah. You are absolutely right. Will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your sec_axis function is not specified correctly:

- the function is sec_axis(), not sec.axis()
- it needs a transformation coefficient (you can choose it arbitrarily for your example, I chose 1)
- you can specify any name you like
- guide = "none" omits any scale-values / ticks on the right side that you do not want to display.

The following works for me:

```
temp.data = data.frame (Species  = rep(c("A","B"),each=2, times=2),
                        Status = rep(c("An","Bac"), times=4),
                        Sex = rep(c("Male","Female"), each=4, times=1),
                        Proportion = c(6.86, 7.65, 30.13, 35.71, 7.13, 10.33, 29.24, 31.09))

p<-ggplot(temp.data, aes(x = Species, y = Proportion, fill = Status)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = position_dodge(width = 0.73), width=.67) +
  facet_grid(Sex ~ .) + xlab("X title") + 
  ylab("Y title") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Status", labels = c("A","B"),
                    values = c("#0d4e04","#a36424")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis( trans=~.*1, name="Sex", guide = "none"))
```